# How does Wireless Carplay Adapter work?

Tags: ios, wifi, car-integration

I am really interesting in buying a wireless CarPlay adapter (like https://carplay2air.com/).  I want to use Carplay without the need to connect a Lightning cable.

Before doing this, I would really like know how these kind of adapters actually work.

Is there some kind of an exploit they are using? If so, I would be afraid of having a really expensive black box as soon as iOS is updated in the future.

Comment: Bluetooth and Wifi, as stated on the webpage.

Comment: Flatten your phone battery as you drive… not seeing the benefit. I'll continue to plug mine in to my CarPlay, thanks ;)

Comment: Actually I would like to get an idea of how these adapters work, to maybe hack a solution on my own.